# Как заменить русскую букву по позиции?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь рандомно заменять русские буквы на английские:

```
$trans = array(
    'и' => 'U',
    'р' => 'P',
    'е' => 'E',
);

$str = 'Привет';
$res = replace($str, $trans);

echo $res;

function replace($str, $trans)
{
  for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strwidth($str); $i++) {
    if (rand(0,1) and isset($trans[$str[$i]])) $str[$i] = $trans[$str[$i]];
  }

  return $str;
}
```

Но вот только замена не срабатывает, я как понял из за того что буквы русские, и позицию неверно считывает скрипт. Как можно подобное сделать с русскими буквами чтобы при этом слово не ломалось?

Comment: str_replace разве умеет заменять по позиции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *не срабатывает, я как понял из за того что буквы русские*

Да, так и есть. Для кириллицы нужно использовать нечто вроде `preg_split()`. Эта функция корректно разбивает исходную строку на массив символов *(в вашем случае - букв)*, и далее нужно обрабатывать этот массив *(а не исходную строку, как было в вашем коде)*:

```
$trans = array(
    'и' => 'U',
    'р' => 'P',
    'е' => 'E',
);

$str = 'Привет';

$res = replace($str, $trans);
echo $res;


function replace($str, $trans) {
    $tmp = preg_split('~~u', $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strwidth($str); $i++) {
        if (rand(0, 1) & isset($trans[$tmp[$i]])) {
            $tmp[$i] = $trans[$tmp[$i]];
        }
    }

    return join($tmp);
}
```